# If statement put in wrong place

Tags: javascript, if-statement, background-color, gsap

In order to make some test on TweenMax I'm doing a simple "catch-the-color" game however it looks like I do some error in my code as everything is fine but a single if statement that should end the game. I guess that the problem is not with the color changer itself but with the place where I put the if statement. I'm pretty new to programming so there are high chances I made some silly mistake.

You can take a look at the entire page here: https://codepen.io/IvanRoselli/pen/vbqjoo

And here's the Javascript I used

```
var colorCircle = document.getElementById('circle');
var startBtn = document.getElementById('start-btn');
var catchBtn = document.getElementById('catch-btn');
var mainTitle = document.getElementById('main-title');
var colorChange = new TimelineMax({repeat: -1});
var circleBackgroundColor = document.getElementById('circle').style.backgroundColor;
var colorCircle = document.getElementById('circle');
var startBtn = document.getElementById('start-btn');
var catchBtn = document.getElementById('catch-btn');
var mainTitle = document.getElementById('main-title');
var colorChange = new TimelineMax({repeat: -1});
var circleBackgroundColor = 
document.getElementById('circle').style.backgroundColor;

function playPause(){
    colorChange.paused(!colorChange.paused()); 
}

function getIt(){
     $('#catch-btn').click(function(){
        if(circleBackgroundColor === 'blue'){
            mainTitle.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
            return;
        } else {
            mainTitle.innerHTML = "Try again pressing CATCH"; 
            playPause();
        }
    })
}

function startGame(){
    getIt();
    $('#start-btn').css("display", "none");
    $('#catch-btn').css("display", "inline");
    $(colorCircle).css("cursor", "pointer");
    colorChange.from(colorCircle, .5, {backgroundColor: 'orange', ease: SteppedEase.config(1)});
    colorChange.to(colorCircle, .5, {backgroundColor: 'red', ease: SteppedEase.config(1)});
    colorChange.to(colorCircle, .5, {backgroundColor: 'pink', ease: SteppedEase.config(1)});
    colorChange.to(colorCircle, .5, {backgroundColor: 'yellow', ease: SteppedEase.config(1)});
    colorChange.to(colorCircle, .5, {backgroundColor: 'blue', ease: SteppedEase.config(1)});
    colorChange.to(colorCircle, .5, {backgroundColor: 'green', ease: SteppedEase.config(1)});
    colorChange.to(colorCircle, .5, {backgroundColor: 'cyan', ease: SteppedEase.config(1)});


};


$('#start-btn').click(function() {
    startGame();
});
```

Basically the H1 should change between "You Won" if you catch the blue or "Try Again" for other colors.

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Comment: `circleBackgroundColor` is being set once (well, twice for some reason) but it won't dynamically update as the color changes. You should set it again when the user clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I have made some changes and its working fine for me.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NoZBPz
```

Problem is its giving rgb value and app is also not stopping on won also changed the if condition.

```
if((document.getElementById('circle').style.backgroundColor) === 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
            mainTitle.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
          playPause();
            return;
        } else {
            mainTitle.innerHTML = "Try again pressing CATCH"; 
            playPause();
        }
```

Comment: Great, I had a doubt about using rgb and I’ve even tried but clearly I was doing some mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, see the function below.
You have to catch the color of the element during the onclick event , this means the color is caught on click of the button 
whereas in your case the color is caught during load and it never changes.
I have used rgb format for the conditional checks.

```
function getIt(){
    $('#catch-btn').click(function(){
       circleBackgroundColor = document.getElementById('circle').style.backgroundColor;
        if(circleBackgroundColor == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'){
            mainTitle.innerHTML = "YOU WON!";
            return;
        } else {
            mainTitle.innerHTML = "Try again pressing CATCH"; 
            playPause();
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)